# Belt (singing) exercises and techniques?

Tags: technique, voice, exercises

So, I have worked hard to develop a middle voice and head voice but it doesn't have the really powerful tone of a belt voice. Can anyone give me audio exercises or refer some source for belting techniques and exercises? 
Is there any Estill Teacher who can write down some theory and offer exercises in response to this question? 
I was refered Singing and the Actor and Belt Voice training but currently I do not have funds to buy these. If anyone has mp3s from these programs, please upload.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I posted this as answer, but it's not designed as one. I did it to have more room. :)

Belting technique should really only be attempted after a thorough understanding of the mechanics and technique of singing, and at least a baseline amount of classical technique. It takes most singers years to get to a point where they can develop their belting voice naturally and safely. Vocal health is a HUGE issue here; I can't emphasize that enough. Many pop stars have suffered from poor technique, most recently Adele, but victims abound.

http://voicecouncil.com/has-adele-been-a-bad-girl/

I cannot tell for sure from your question, but I get the feeling (correct me if I'm wrong) that you've not taken in-person lessons before. That's fine, and you can accomplish some basic technique, including breath support, pitch control, etc. on your own. However I have to say that belting is **not** something you should try without a teachers assistance, *in person*. There's really no substitute for it. Even some teachers, teaching *in person* lessons have trouble explaining what must be done in a mutually understood way. When you're referring to hidden body muscles that are required to do incredibly complex things, everyone's going to describe things a different way.

If you're at all serious about learning to sing, concentrate on healthy, classical technique for awhile. (Note classical doesn't *necessarily* refer to classical music.) Try as hard as you can to find a good teacher you can connect with. They may be expensive, but it's cheaper than vocal surgery, and much better than ruining your voice for life. Too many people try to push their voice too hard, too early, and with too little technique. They pay a steep price for it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the previous comment in light, it is also important to develop a good practice routine.
You should treat your voice like you would any other muscle; warm-up than exercise.  Humming and Vocal Fry is awesome for a warm up routine, and for developing strength and smoothness, Lip trills are indispensable.